# Overlapping edges after node expansion

Tags: vis.js

I'm using vis js to build an application and when I generate the first search I don't have edges overlapping but after expanding a node I got them.
[image: whitout overlapping]
[image: with overlapping]
I have a loop to fill the nodes and edges using nodes.update and edges.update

Graph:

```
    var container = document.getElementById("graph-container");
        var data = {
          nodes: nodes,
          edges: edges,
        };
        
        var options = {
            interaction:{
                dragNodes:true,
                dragView: true,
                hover: true,
                hoverConnectedEdges: true,
                selectConnectedEdges: true,
                zoomView: true                
            },
            layout:{
                randomSeed : 2,
                improvedLayout:true,
                clusterThreshold: 150,
            },  
            physics: {
                barnesHut: {
                avoidOverlap: 0.5
                }
            },      
            nodes: {
                physics:false,
                borderWidth:3,
                size:14,
                font:{color:'#000000'}                
            },
            edges:{
                length: 200,
                smooth: {
                    roundness: 0.2,
                    type: 'dynamic'
                },                         
                font:{
                    size:9,
                }    
            }               
        };
        if(is not expand node){
            network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);  
        }else{
            network.fit();
            network.redraw();
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?? I think its not reading my options = {...} in the expansion